# Does pca.explained_variance_ratio_ sort in descending order?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, pca

I'm conducting a principal component analysis in python on the following df:

(my actual df is much larger but this gives the general idea of my problem).

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 6 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 3 | 10 | 9 |
| 24 | 23 | 19 | 2 | 10 | 21 | 10 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 10 | 11 | 18 |

I've conducted the pca as follows:

```
sklearn.decomposition.PCA

pca = PCA()

pca.fit_transform(df)

ratios = pca.explained_variance_ratio_
```

output:

```
[8.33009934e-01 1.39113795e-01 2.25784605e-02 5.29780973e-03
 2.25016200e-34]
```

Does anyone know if the pca.explained_variance_ratio_ attribute delivers the values in the order of the columns (i.e. 1,2,3,4,5...) so that the first value corresponds to column 1, the second to column 2 and so forth, or in order of descending contribution to variance?

Comment: There is insufficient code. Which PCA are you referring to ?  presumable `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` ?

Comment: Sorry, yeah that's what I'm using